# Can you send an external message from an Azure SQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: azure-sql-database, servicebus

Is it possible in a stored procedure running in Azure SQL to send information to an outside application?  Boss is more comfortable with sql and stored procedures and would like to generate a notification and have it processed ASAP externally.

Methods we've used before with our own SQL Server are [Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker) and [CLR Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx).  I thought there would be some integration with [Azure Service Bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/), but I can't find anything about generating a message from SQL Server.

If we want to generate some action from a stored procedure in SQL Server, are we stuck with creating our own table and polling it from an external application?

Comment: I think you are left with last option